# Micronaut Embedded Server vs localhost

Tags: java, junit, micronaut, embedded-server

I'm getting started with micronaut and I would like to understand the difference between testing the controller using local host and using an Embedded server

For example
I have a simple controller

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {

  @Get("/test")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String index() {
    return "Hello World";
  }  
}
```

and the tested class

```
@MicronautTest
public class HelloControllerTest {

  @Inject
  @Client("/hello")
  RxHttpClient helloClient;

  @Test
  public void testHello() {
    HttpRequest<String> request = HttpRequest.GET("/test");
    String body = helloClient.toBlocking().retrieve(request);

    assertNotNull(body);
    assertEquals("Hello World", body);
  }
}
```

I got the logs:

```
14:32:54.382 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG mylogger - Sending HTTP Request: GET /hello/test
14:32:54.382 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG mylogger - Chosen Server: localhost(51995)
```

But then, in which cases we need an Embedded Server? why?
where I can find documentation to understand it. I read the documentation from Micronaut but is not clear for me, what is actually occurring and why?
like this example:

```
 @Test
  public void testIndex() throws Exception {

    EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);

    RxHttpClient client = server.getApplicationContext().createBean(RxHttpClient.class, server.getURL());

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, client.toBlocking().exchange("/hello/status").status());
    server.stop();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, you are using `EmbeddedServer` implementation - `NettyHttpServer`. This is an abstraction that represents Micronaut server implementation (a `NettyHttpServer` in this case).

The main difference is that `micronaut-test` provides components and annotations that make writing Micronaut HTTP unit tests much simpler. Before `micronaut-test`, you had to start up your application manually with:

```
EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)
```

Then you had to prepare an HTTP client, for instance:

```
HttpClient http = HttpClient.create(server.URL)
```

The `micronaut-test` simplifies it to adding `@MicronautTest` annotation over the test class, and the runner starts the embedded server and initializes all beans you can inject. Just like you do with injecting `RxHttpClient` in your example.

The second thing worth mentioning is that the `@MicronautTest` annotation also allows you to use `@MockBean` annotation to override existing bean with some mock you can define at the test level. By default, `@MicronautTest` does not mock any beans, so the application that starts reflect 1:1 application's runtime environment. The same thing happens when you start `EmbeddedServer` manually - this is just a programmatic way of starting a regular Micronaut application.

So the conclusion is quite simple - if you want to write less boilerplate code in your test classes, use `micronaut-test` with all its annotations to make your tests simpler. Without it, you will have to manually control all things (starting Micronaut application, retrieving beans from application context instead of using `@Inject` annotation, and so on.)

Last but not least, here is the same test written without `micronaut-test`:

```
package com.github.wololock.micronaut.products

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer
import spock.lang.AutoCleanup
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class ProductControllerSpec extends Specification {

  @Shared
  @AutoCleanup
  EmbeddedServer server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)

  @Shared
  @AutoCleanup
  HttpClient http = server.applicationContext.createBean(RxHttpClient, server.URL)


  def "should return PROD-001"() {
    when:
    Product product = http.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/product/PROD-001"), Product)

    then:
    product.id == 'PROD-001'

    and:
    product.name == 'Micronaut in Action'

    and:
    product.price == 29.99
  }

  def "should support 404 response"() {
    when:
    http.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/product/PROD-009"))

    then:
    def e = thrown HttpClientResponseException
    e.status == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
  }
}
```

In this case, we can't use `@Inject` annotation and the only way to create/inject beans is to use `applicationContext` object directly. (Keep in mind that in this case, `RxHttpClient` bean does not exist in the context and we have to create it - in `micronaut-test` case this bean is prepared for us upfront.)

And here is the same test that uses `micronaut-test` to make the test much simpler:

```
package com.github.wololock.micronaut.products

import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class ProductControllerSpec extends Specification {

  @Inject
  @Client("/")
  HttpClient http

  def "should return PROD-001"() {
    when:
    Product product = http.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/product/PROD-001"), Product)

    then:
    product.id == 'PROD-001'

    and:
    product.name == 'Micronaut in Action'

    and:
    product.price == 29.99
  }

  def "should support 404 response"() {
    when:
    http.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/product/PROD-009"))

    then:
    def e = thrown HttpClientResponseException
    e.status == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
  }
}
```

Less boilerplate code, and the same effect. We could even `@Inject EmbeddedServer embeddedServer` if would like to access it, but there is no need to do so.